# how to use select query with in = array column data php

Tags: php

I need to get number of row count of leads table = to userIDs. i created a code but it doesn't work.

```
$userID = array(
  array(
    'id' => 1,
      ),
  array(
    'id' => 2,
      ),
  array(
    'id' => 3,
      )
);
```

i need help to pass array column id values to sql "in" query and get all row count equal to userIDs.
here is the code i create..

```
<?php
$connn = dbconnect(); 
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tblleads WHERE assigned IN (' . implode(',', $userID ['id']) . ')';
$rn =  $connn->query($sql);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($rn);
?>

<h1>Lead Count : <?php echo $num_rows; ?>  </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting from MySQL using [IN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in) which is typically:

> Returns 1 (true) if expr is equal to any of the values in the IN() ***list***, else returns 0 (false).

on the other hand you are sending an invalid data by [implode](https://php.net/implode)ing a multi-dimensional array. instead you can mix the use of implode & [array_column](http://php.net/array_column) to get an indexed list to be imploded to be passed to the query.

```
$ids = array_column($userID, 'id');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tblleads WHERE assigned IN (' . implode(',', $ids) . ')';
```

### You must be aware that

you code is open to sql injection which may lead to a security exploits on your code. instead you may use the [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)